# Help trying to find the lifespan of an ancient rabbi

Tags: history, jewish-books, rabbis, beis-hamikdash, zohar

Zohar (Vayikra 10a) quotes a sefer by R. Hamnunab [Hanunah] Sabah, a sage of Second Beit HaMikdash times. Thing is, I can't pin-point the lifespan. Can someone help me with this? Toda.

Comment: https://kotar.cet.ac.il/KotarApp/Index/Chapter.aspx?nBookID=20860004&nTocEntryID=20971485 says here that he lived in Sachnin. And in Hebrew Wikipedia it says that he may have lived even before the Tannaim.

Comment: @Harel13 how does that make any sense? https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.42a.6

Comment: @Heshy please recall that Talmud is known for weaving in generations as if arguing on the spot. I could be wrong in regards to this very instance (Sukkah 42a), but it is my first instinct.

Comment: @Heshy, I'm no expert, which why I said what I said in the name of the sources. However, if you enter רב המנונא in Heb. Wiki. You'll find that there were several individuals with that name. Some googling showed me that there were apparently two individuals with the name Rav Hamnuna Saba. To the best of my limited knowledge, what I wrote is attributed to the first and he's the one that appears in the Zohar.

Comment: @Harel13 thanks for pointing that out, that they're were two R. Hammuna Saba's.

Comment: Do we know there are two R Hamnuna Sabbas if not for the Zohar? Or is the existence of a second earlier one a postulate just to explain how the Zohar could really have been written by a Tanna? Because the alternative is there's really only one Hamnuna Sabba the famous Amora and at least those parts of the Zohar are from later than Rashbi. This would explain why you Rivka couldn't find any biographical details about this alleged person.

Comment: @DoubleAA the fact that there's 'Saba' attached means he's very old. I don't think the Zohar is using him to prove a point--at least not at first glance--or it would have said so. Moreover, the latest comment by Harel13 is sufficient that there were indeed two.

Comment: @Rivka I didn't say the Zohar is trying to prove a point. I'm saying we know there's a Hamnuna Sabba who is an Amora. Then we have the Zohar talking about a Hamnuna Sabba also. So either you conclude that there's another person with the same name who lived earlier who we know nothing else about or you conclude the passages in the Zohar were not written by Rashbi but by someone who lived later. It's the same story as if you found Barack Obama's name written on the US Constitution. Either there was another guy with that name that no one knew about, or the document is not as old as we thought.